# С помощью XMLHttpRequest вывод сообщения на jsp о результате выполнения запроса

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlet, xmlhttprequest

Отправляю данные из формы используя `XMLHttpRequest` в сервлет(Java), но нужно также получить на этой же странице без ее перегрузки сообщение о результате. Может кто-нибудь с опытным взглядом подскажет новичку что делаю не так, был бы очень благодарен

**add.jsp:**

```
<h1 id='result'></h1> //тут должно выводиться сообщение о результате
<h2>Add student</h2>
<form>
    <input type = "text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
    <input type = "text" id="secondname" name="secondname"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Add student" onclick="add()">
</form>
```

**js:**

```
   function add() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var surname = document.getElementById("secondname").value;
        var button = document.getElementById("button").value;
        dat = "firstname="+encodeURIComponent(firstname)+"&secondname="+encodeURIComponent(secondname)+"&button="+encodeURIComponent(button);   
        xhr.open('POST', 'servlet', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        xhr.send(dat); 
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { //этот код не работает, выскакивает alert(200)
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                var response = xhr.responseText;
            } else {
                 alert(xmlHttp.status);
            }
        };
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = response;
    }
```

**сервлет:**

```
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
      if(request.getParameter("button".equals("Add student")){
          if(request.getParameter("firstname").matches("[A-Za-z]{2,}") && request.getParameter("secondname").matches("[A-Za-z]{2,}")) {
                studentDao.create(new Student(0, request.getParameter("firstname"), request.getParameter("secondname")));
                response.getWriter().write("Student successfully added to the Database!");
            } else {
                response.getWriter().write("Student has not been added to the Database, input correct data!");
            }
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/add.jsp").forward(request, response);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xhr.onload = function () { 
  var response = xhr.responseText;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = response;
};
```